# how to reset clickToggle function if another event happened halfway through

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so basically, i am trying to do a click toggle that will expand out a overlaying div, this code works great.

```
    // plugin for clickToggle
    (function($) {
        $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
            var funcs = [func1, func2];
            this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
            this.click(function() {
                var data = $(this).data();
                var tc = data.toggleclicked;
                $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
                data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
            });
            return this;
        };
    }($));

    $(function() {
       $("#toggle").clickToggle(function() {
            $(".log").html("click Toggle1, show tab panel");
            $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
            $(".container").addClass("overlay-disable");

        },function() {
            $(".log").html("click Toggle2, hide tab panel");
            $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
            $(".container").removeClass("overlay-disable");
        });
   });
```

As my overlaying div does not cover the whole page, it covers about 60% in width, so i decided to add one more event inbetween to check if user click outside of the overlying div, if they did, it will trigger the result of closing it

Latest code:

```
    $(function() {
       $("#toggle").clickToggle(function() {
            $(".log").html("click Toggle1, show tab panel");
            $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
            $(".container").addClass("overlay-disable");

            $(".container").click(function() {
                $(".container").unbind("click");
                $(".log").html("panel hide success");
                $("#toggle_content").hide();
                $(".container").removeClass("overlay-disable");
            }); 


        },function() {
            $(".log").html("click Toggle2, hide tab panel");
            $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
            $(".container").removeClass("overlay-disable");
        });
   });
```

Now the problem is if i click outside the overlay `div(.container)`, it close well, but when i click on my tab to open it again, it will run the exiting `function(toggle2)` instead of restarting back to the first `function(toggle1)`.

I tried to do `("#toggle").unbind("clickToggle");` but to no avail, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to add a class to the rest of the page when your div is covering 60% of your page and only then capture the close div event.

Comment: yup the class overlay-disable is to disable anyone from clicking any things like dropdown menu from the underlying div. So i believe it will only capture the close div

Comment: I got stuck at "... so i decided to add one more event inbetween ...", which makes no sense at all.

Comment: why? my tab open and close(toggle state), i added another user behaviour which is that user might click outside of the overlaying div instead of the tab, so i took that into consideration and added another exit function, when they exit through that way it doesn't reset the toggle function, so the next time i click on the tab, it will start at step 2 of the toggle function which is an exit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question does not "add one more event inbetween". A better summary would be that it "temporarily adds a click handler". The point being that a hander is not an event, but something that responds to an event.

Going one step further, the "temporary" click handler is only removed if the container is clicked. If it is not clicked, then it will remain in place and the next toggle cycle will add *another* identical click handler to the container. If you are to stick with this approach, then you should ensure that the "temporary" click handler is unbound before adding a new one.

That said, an accumulation of click handlers is not particularly harmful in this case, but undesirable. All will be unbound if/when the container is eventually clicked. In many applications, an accumulation of click handlers would be highly undesirable.

Several other points :

1. Your `clickToggle` plugin is an over-elaboration. There are simpler ways, using standard jQuery methods, to toggle between two actions on successive clicks. A standard trick is to `.toggleClass()` then immediately test state with `.hasClass()` and branch accordingly. Sometimes, you might need to introduce a dummy class just to register state but in your case, you already toggle the container's 'overlay-disable' class.
2. jQuery's maintains a built-in toggle state for tracking 'toggle' actions. This state will remain unaware of `.hide()`. By using `.animate({width:'toggle'}` again, but with zero duration, you can achieve the hide effect and maintain the built-in toggle state.
3. If you want to bind/unbind an event handler, then it's more efficient to do so with a named function, but here it is simpler and clearer to *permanently* attach a click handler to the container and, as before, use `hasClass()` to test state and branch accordingly.
4. To give a better user experience, it is often a good idea to issue `stop(true)` on a repeatedly animated element. Without stopping, (particularly with longer animations) the effects queue can build up and the ui can appear unresponsive, even quirky. Sometimes you might want `stop(true,true)` and sometimes `stop(true,false)` (see [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)).

I would do something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggle").on('click', function() {
        $("#toggle_content").stop(true,false).animate({width:'toggle'}, 350);
        $(".container").toggleClass('overlay-disable');
        if($(".container").hasClass('overlay-disable')) {
            $(".log").html("click Toggle1, show tab panel");
        } else {
            $(".log").html("click Toggle2, hide tab panel");
        }
    });

    $(".container").on('click', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('overlay-disable')) {
            $("#toggle_content").stop(true,false).animate({width:'toggle'}, 0);//zero duration will give 'hide' effect
            $(this).removeClass("overlay-disable");
            $(".log").html("panel hide: success");
        } else {
            $(".log").html("panel hide: not this time");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you gave me a lot of knowledge. thumbs up

Comment: Cool. Some of the points are difficult to express concisely. I hope they are comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

$(".container").unbind("click");
its mean you inactive/remove event click of div container, so at the second time, the code $(".container").click() will never run